# Random Generated word changes when flipping between portrait and landscape

Tags: java, arrays, resources, random, orientation

I have an array in `res/values/array.xml`.

```
<string-array name="list">
    <item>string 1</item>
    <item>string 2</item>
    <item>string 3</item>
</string-array>
```

And this is my Java-Code without the import-statements.

```
public class Study extends Activity {

    private String[] myString;
    public static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.study);

        Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
        tv.setText(q);

    }
}
```

It displays a random item from the `array.xml` into a TextView with the id of word. Everything works out fine. That is until I switch from portrait to landscape, or vice versa, then it displays another random item. When I switch back and forth I would like it to keep the same item originally displayed. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I needed the onSaveInstanceState() to find the string and store it and then the onRestoreInstanceState() to display it in the right spot after the activity is restarted. Here's the code and thank you sincerely for the help.

public class Study extends Activity {

```
private String[] myString;
public static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.study);

    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);

    String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    TextView word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
    word.setText(q);

}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView wordTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);
    String wordText = wordTextView.getText().toString();

    savedInstanceState.putString("wordText", wordText);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  TextView wordTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);

  String wordText = savedInstanceState.getString("wordText");
  wordTextView.setText(wordText);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Changing orientation actually kills the Activity and starts a new one. So in your case `onCreate()` is called again and random word is generated again.

Put some `Log.i("created/destroyed")` in your `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` to see this.

Comment: I don't have much experience with android development yet, how would I do this?

Comment: Just put `Log.i("MyActivity created")` inside your `onCreate(..)` method. Then take a look at android log.

Comment: You have to `import android.util.Log;`

Comment: Hmm, small mistake. Usage is `Log.i("MyActivity", "created")`

Comment: I tried super.onCreate(Log.i("MyActivity", "created")); where I get the same error and putting it after where I also get the same error. Is there something else that needs to go in?